# Install Selenium for Python 3.6 (Ubuntu 17.04)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, virtualenv

Working through a book on TDD that uses Python 3.6 features, including a formatted string, but as the command `python3` defaults to 3.5 even though I have Python 3.6 installed, it returns an invalid syntax error when I try to run my unit test. On the other hand, pip3 installs Selenium to a Python3.5 directory, so when I try to run the tests using 3.6, I get a 'no module named selenium' error.

I am working in a virtualenv, but while python3.5 shows up in `/home/username/.virtualenvs/projectname/lib`, python3.6 does not even though running pip3 in the virtualenv returns `python3.6 is already the newest version (3.6.1-1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explicit versions:

```
pip3.6 install Selenium
```

or

```
python3.6 -m pip install Selenium
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, hope it helps:

**Create virtualenv with path to needed interpreter version:**

```
virtualenv -p /path_to_your_python_3.6/ myenv
```

**Check the version:**

```
. ./myenv/bin/activate && python -V
```

Once you in your venv environment **install Selenium**:

```
pip3 install Selenium
```